# Plot $z=e^{i\theta}\sin{\theta}$ in the complex plane as $\theta$ varies from $0$ to $2\pi$ and describe the shape of the curve near the origin

Tags: complex-numbers, complex-geometry

I have written $\sin{\theta}$ as $\frac{i}{2}\left(e^{-i\theta}-e^{i\theta}\right)$, and then rearranged to get:
$$z - \frac{i}{2}=-\frac{1}{2}e^{i\left(2\theta +\frac{\pi}{2}\right)}$$

However I am not sure how to sketch this. I assume it will be centred on the point $\left(0,\frac{1}{2}\right)$ because of the $\frac{i}{2}$, but I have no idea what shape it will be.

Comment: $f(\theta)=e^{i\theta}$ as $\theta$ varies from $0$ to $2\pi$ is the unit circle where $\theta$ is the angle, anticlockwise from the positive real axis in an Argand diagram. Think about what the function will look like, if for each value of $\theta,$ you multiply the function by $\sin\theta.$

Comment: @AdamRubinson so will it be in the shape of a vertical infinity sign? So for $\theta=0$ and $\theta=\pi$, it will be equal to zero, but as $\theta$ approaches $\frac{\pi}{2}$ it will increase until it begins to match the unit circle

Comment: sounds right to me, although I’m rusty on complex analysis, so don’t take my word as gospel.

Comment: $e^{i(2\theta+\pi/2)}$ is still just the unit circle, now traversed two times counterclockwise starting from $e^{i\pi/2} = i$. Scale that _circle_ by $-1/2$ and translate it by $i/2$. There's no figure-eight shape.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write $$x + iy = z = (\cos \theta + i \sin \theta) \sin \theta = \cos \theta \sin \theta + i \sin^2 \theta = \frac 12 \sin(2\theta) + \frac i2 (1 - \cos 2\theta)$$ so a parametric representation is $$x = \frac 12 \sin 2\theta,\quad y = \frac 12 (1 - \cos 2\theta).$$ Note that $x^2 + (y-\frac 12)^2 = \frac 14$.  What type of shape do such points lie on?

Comment: So it will be a circle centred at $\left(0,\frac{1}{2}\right)$ with radius $\frac{1}{2}$?